# SPMetal generating unique enums for each choice field with same values

Tags: choice-field, spmetal

I use SPMetal on two lists on my SharePoint site and there are several columns with choice field who have the same choices.

```
<Field Name='Colors1' Type='Choice'>
  <CHOICES>
      <CHOICE>BLUE</CHOICE>
      <CHOICE>GREEN</CHOICE>
  <CHOICES>
</Field>
<Field Name='Colors2' Type='Choice'>
      <CHOICES>
          <CHOICE>BLUE</CHOICE>
          <CHOICE>GREEN</CHOICE>
      <CHOICES>
</Field>
```

SPMetal now creates two properties for class1 and 2 (which I want) but also with different types

```
public System.Nullable<Colors1> Colors1 {...}
public System.Nullable<Colors2> Colors2 {...}
```

How can I configure the Parameters.xml to use the same enum for every of these color choices?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation and resolved it using a separate column definition (in Visual Studio).

Comment: Please provide more details.